# how __spec_install_post work in RPM Packaging

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm checkcing binary strip in RPM Packaging and get this:

```
__spec_install_post:
    ...
    __os_install_post
    ...

__os_install_post:
    ...
    %{!?_debug_package:     /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip %
    {_strip}
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note %{_strip} %{_objdump}
     }
    ...
```

I didn't find anywhere in use of `__spec_install_post`.

Is this macro directly invoked by rpmbuild? A Documentation will be great.

It seems there's many a lot 'leaf like' macro in invoke chain. that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I only found some references in some bugs and stuff; these seem to be magic undocumented macros that are run at certain stages, *e.g.* for yours right "post" the "install" stanza of your specfile.

An actual list would be great, but I think you'll only find what you already had by digging in `/[usr]/lib/rpm/macros` etc.